# Very Slow Query in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, optimization, database-performance

I have a scenario like;

I have a table named "`tbl_gust_comb_archve_01nov11_beyond`"

Indexed keys are set on these fields "`Gid`, `gip`, `siteid`, `kw`, `kwtype`, `dt`, `gpage`, `dated`"

And

This is my query:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS 
  gid, gip, siteid, kw, kwtype, dt, count(id) as vpage, sum(mapped) as mapped 
FROM 
  tbl_gust_comb_archve_01nov11_beyond 
WHERE 
  confirmation = 1 
AND 
  dated BETWEEN '2012-01-31' AND '2012-01-31' 
AND 
  siteid = 'bing' 
GROUP BY gid 
ORDER BY dt 
DESC LIMIT 0,50
```

If you make the date a RANGE such as `'2012-01-31' AND '2012-02-01'` then the result will take longer then 10-30 minutes.

If you have a date range and REMOVE the "`GROUP BY`" then the result will be much faster (about 5 minutes). Though! after removing `GROUP BY`, 5 minutes are also too much...

Table size is "30mill records and 12Gig".

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried running these queries with EXPLAIN? That should always be your first step in this situation

Answer (score 1):

You should first [do `EXPLAIN` on the query](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html), as Mark Baker suggested within his comment.

But probably creating a multi-column index on these columns should solve the problem:

- `dt` (this probably should be the first)
- `confirmation`
- `dated`
- `siteid`
- `gid`

I am not sure how the `gid` should be indexed (on which position, etc.).

More details are here, so you can decide on the solution on your own:

- [How MySQL Uses Indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html),
- [`CREATE INDEX` Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html),
- [`ORDER BY` Optimization](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html),
- [`GROUP BY` Optimization](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-optimization.html),

Answer (score 0):

If *siteid* does not vary a lot, you can try to remove your index on *siteid*. 
If you have 30mill. record and 1/3 with *siteid* == "bing", then your query will

1. Grab those 10mill. record
2. Apply your *dated* lookup afterwards, on those 10 mill. records, which can be really slow.

It's quite logical, since selecting a range is, normally, longer than selecting a simple value. If *siteid* does vary a lot, you can try to add a dual index on both *dated* & *siteid*.

For *confirmation* field, since you are in a archive table, maybe you can move those who have not confirmed to an other table. You can also gain some speed if you are able to remove this check.